# How to convert Latitude and Longitude to Orientation (Yaw, Pitch, Roll)

Tags: java, trigonometry

I have a 3D aircraft model in WorldWind a 3D earth model which runs on OpenGL Java. I update the position of this model with data from an database that includes lat, lon, and alt. What is the method to get the heading information (Yaw, pitch, roll) from current position and update position?

Comment: You can't get orientation data from positional data - the two are not related.

Comment: Couldn't you get direction from the current position and update position?

Comment: Yes - direction is not orientation.

Comment: Keep in mind this is an aircraft whose nose points towards its direction of movement.

Comment: Several hundred hours in light aircraft and I never flew in one like that.

Comment: Ok Imagine a rocket instead.

Comment: Not true for rockets either. To deal with aircraft flight modelling you must have some basic physics knowledge (Newton's laws of motion). It seems you are being too ambitious.

Comment: I have some advanced physics knowledge and I actually got it to work. When I said imagine a rocket I was referring to the model only moving in one NED vector.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, with latitude longitude and altitude I converted them into ECEF coords. Then found the direction from

```
        d(x,y,z) = (Destination(x,y,z) - Origin(x,y,z))

        double yaw   = -Math.atan2(dx,-dz);
        double pitch = Math.atan2(dy, Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dz * dz)));
```

Comment: Hi how you calculated dx, dy, dz ?

Comment: It's just the difference of 2 points' xyz values. x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1

Answer (score 0):

This is user758114 for the advice and incredible solution. This is just the same script but in #C. This works with a GeoLocation API, so this is tested.

```java
class ECEF {
    public static class OrientationResult {
        public double yaw;
        public double pitch;

        public OrientationResult(double yaw, double pitch) {
            this.yaw = yaw;
            this.pitch = pitch;
        }
    }

    public static OrientationResult getOrientation(double lat1, double alt1, double lon1, double lat2, double alt2, double lon2) {
        double dx = lat1 - lat2;
        double dy = alt1 - alt2;
        double dz = lon1 - lon2;
        return orientationDifference(dx, dy, dz);
    }

    private static OrientationResult orientationDifference(double dx, double dy, double dz) {
        double yaw = -Math.atan2(dx, -dz);
        double pitch = Math.atan2(dy, Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + dz * dz));
        return new OrientationResult(yaw, pitch);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is specifically tagged as a Java question, and is framed around using a library in Java. Please avoid adding answers in other languages, as it adds noise to the answers and can cause confusion for future readers.

Comment: I edited the code for java